# why mixedsort not working as expected when using decimal values

Tags: r

mixedsort from gtools not working as expected. Example below:

```
library(gtools)
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 8))
x <- c("buckets")
colnames(df) <- x
buc = c("-Inf","0.5","1.5","2.5","7.5",  "11.5", "27.5", "Inf")
df$buckets <- buc
df$buckets <- (as.character(df$buckets))
df$rank = as.numeric(as.character(order(mixedsort(df$buckets))))
print(df)
```

I expected 2.5 to be ranked before 7.5 but it didnt work.

Comment: Your issue is that you use `order`. `mixedsort` sorts correctly, then `order` gives the alphabetical order. Maybe you want `mixedorder(df$buckets)` instead of `order(mixedsort(df$bucket))`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using `mixedsort` as if it is `mixedorder`.

```
buc = c("-Inf","0.5","1.5","2.5","7.5",  "11.5", "27.5", "Inf")
# rearrange a couple for a more robust example
xx = buc[c(2, 1, 4, 3, 8, 7, 6, 5)]
xx
# [1] "0.5"  "-Inf" "2.5"  "1.5"  "Inf"  "27.5" "11.5" "7.5" 
mixedsort(xx) #correct
[1] "-Inf" "0.5"  "1.5"  "2.5"  "7.5"  "11.5" "27.5" "Inf" 

order(mixedsort(xx)) # pretty useless - tells us that after sorting they are in order
# [1] 1 2 3 6 4 7 5 8

mixedorder(xx) # useful - tells us how to sort them. Probably what you want?
[1] 2 1 4 3 8 7 6 5

identical(xx[mixedorder(xx)], mixedsort(xx)) # we can use the mixedorder to get the mixed sort
# [1] TRUE

df$rank = mixedorder(df$buckets)
df
#   buckets rank
# 1    -Inf    1
# 2     0.5    2
# 3     1.5    3
# 4     2.5    4
# 5     7.5    5
# 6    11.5    6
# 7    27.5    7
# 8     Inf    8

# if the data started out of order, you could also
# order it, then assign the ranks
df = df[mixedorder(df$buckets), ]
df$rank = 1:nrow(df)
```

Comment: Not entirely topic-related but your answer made me realize that I often do this mistake, and I am far from being the only one.
This confusion between (mixed)sort and (mixed)order can lead to problematic situation:  for example I was using mixedsort within a data.table, and this duplicated some rows.
Instinctively you just think a simple sorting on a column should use sort(), but order() is the one that works.